# Question on velocity of gas at specific wavelengths

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I am not a physics guru & hope someone can help.

What is the formula to determine the velocity of a gas on the surface of the Sun relative to the OBSERVER?
The gas has a triple-peaked spectrum, one part of it is red-shifted and the  other peaks is blue-shifted. 
I just don't know what the formula for the velocity is relative to the observer. 
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$v \approx \dfrac {\Delta \lambda}{\lambda}c$ where $v$ is the speed of the particle, along the line joining the particle to the observer, emitting light of wavelength $\lambda$, $c$ is the speed of light and $\Delta \lambda$ is the change in the wavelength.

If the wavelengths gets less then the particle is moving towards the observer (blue shift) and if the wavelength increases then the particle is moving away from the observer (red shift).

As the Sum is rotating then the light from the part of the Sun spinning towards the observer will be blue shifted relative to the light from the Sum which is moving away from the observer.
The parts of the Sun where the rotation of the Sun is at right angles to the line joining the Sun to the observer will not be Doppler shifted.

A "dopplergram" of the Sun in false colour/brightness can be produced which shows where the Sun is moving towards the Earth  (darker colours on the left) and and where it is moving away from the Earth (lighter colours on the right).

The non-uniformity of the colour shows that the Sun is not rotating as a solid body and that there are circulation currents on the surface of the Sun.

[image]